# Import-pssession SQLPS throws "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am running PS script from the client machine (Win7) that does not have SQLPS (Ms SQL Server Database Engine) installed.

The script is doing a bunch of SQL queries from two different SQL servers that have the same version (let's call it **source** and **destination**).

As the client machine does not have SQLPS installed, I decided to use import-pssession functionality.

Unfortunately, when I import the SQLPS module the third/fourth time, it throws the "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error.

To simplify what I want, the following is the snippet of my code:

```
#SQL Query to find out the default folder for sql backup on the SQL SERVER 
$tempSQLQuery = "EXECUTE [master].dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'BackupDirectory'"

#Source
#Get SQL App Server Credential
$MyCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $($sourceSQLServer + "\" + $sourceSQLServerUsername) -Message "Enter SQL application server Username and Password"
Write-Output "Import SQLPS from source SQL app server"
$Global:P_sourceSQLRemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $sourceSQLServer -Authentication negotiate -Credential $MyCredential     
$sessionID = Import-PSSession -Session $Global:P_sourceSQLRemoteSession -Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
Write-Output "Run query against source SQL Server"
#Run query against source SQL
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sourceSQLServerInstance -username $sourceSQLServerSA -password $sourceSQLServerSAPassword -query $tempSQLQuery 

#Destination
#Get SQL App Server Credential
$MyCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $($destinationSQLServer + "\" + $destinationSQLServerUsername) -Message "Enter SQL application server Username and Password"
Write-Output "Import SQLPS from destination SQL app server"
$Global:P_destinationSQLRemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $destinationSQLServer -Authentication negotiate -Credential $MyCredential
$sessionID = Import-PSSession -Session $Global:P_destinationSQLRemoteSession -Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
Write-Output "Run query against destination SQL Server"
#Run the same query, against destination SQL server
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $destinationSQLServerInstance -username $destinationSQLServerSA -password $destinationSQLServerSAPassword -query $tempSQLQuery 
#Remove session / cleanup
#Remove-PSSession -Session $Global:P_destinationSQLRemoteSession
```

Now, let's say, I am not importing the SQLPS from the destination SQL server:

```
#SQL Query to find out the default folder for sql backup on the SQL SERVER 
$tempSQLQuery = "EXECUTE [master].dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'BackupDirectory'"

#Source
#Get SQL App Server Credential
$MyCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $($sourceSQLServer + "\" + $sourceSQLServerUsername) -Message "Enter SQL application server Username and Password"
Write-Output "Import SQLPS from source SQL app server"
$Global:P_sourceSQLRemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $sourceSQLServer -Authentication negotiate -Credential $MyCredential     
$sessionID = Import-PSSession -Session $Global:P_sourceSQLRemoteSession -Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
Write-Output "Run query against source SQL Server"
#Run query against source SQL
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sourceSQLServerInstance -username $sourceSQLServerSA -password $sourceSQLServerSAPassword -query $tempSQLQuery 
#Remove session / cleanup
#Remove-PSSession -Session $Global:P_sourceSQLRemoteSession

#Destination - with same SQLPS module from source SQL app server
#Get SQL App Server Credential
$MyCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $($destinationSQLServer + "\" + $destinationSQLServerUsername) -Message "Enter SQL application server Username and Password"
Write-Output "Run query against destination SQL Server using source SQL imported module"
#Run the same query, against destination SQL server
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $destinationSQLServerInstance -username $destinationSQLServerSA -password $destinationSQLServerSAPassword -query $tempSQLQuery**
```

The following error is resulted:
    A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

What do you think could cause this issue?
Can you think of an alternative method to achieve what I want? should I just have the client machine that will run PS1 script to install SQL module/add-on?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: The [`sqlserver` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/) is the successor of SQLPS and can be installed on any machine, regardless of whether it also has SQL Server installed, so there's really not much benefit to remoting it. For maximum ease of use, use `Install-Module`. (You may need to upgrade PowerShell for that, though -- which is also worth it. PowerShell 5 comes with WMF 5.1 and installs on W7 SP1.)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! I tried to run "Install-Module -Name SqlServer"; it is now asking me to install nuget but then failed "Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider'
tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:5921 char:21"